# How does $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=3} \frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+1}dz=sin(t)$ when $t>0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

How does $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=3} \frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+1}dz=sin(t)$ when $t>0$?

My class is working on the Cauchy Integral Formula currently. Here is my work:

The zeros are z=1,-1 so both lie within the circle we're integrating over.

$\int_{|z|=3} \frac{e^{zt}}{(z+1)(z-1)}dz$

Then using partial fractions:
$\int_{|z|=3} \frac{\frac{e^{t}}{2}}{(z-1)}dz$-$\int_{|z|=3} \frac{\frac{e^{-t}}{2}}{(z+1)}dz$

=$2\pi i f(1)$-$2\pi i f(-1)$

=$2\pi i \frac{e^t}{2}$-$2\pi i \frac{e^{-t}}{2}$

=$\pi i e^t$-$\pi ie^{-t}$

I think I'm missing some relationship between $e^t$ and $sin(t)$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The roots aren't at $1$ and $-1$, they are at $i$ and $-i$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The roots of the denominator are $\pm\mathrm i$, not $\pm1$. The partial fraction decomposition should then come out as $\frac{\mathrm i\mathrm e^{zt}}{2}\left(\frac{1}{z+\mathrm i}-\frac{1}{z-\mathrm i}\right)$. In the end, you should get

$2\pi\mathrm i\frac{\mathrm i}{2}\left(\mathrm e^{-\mathrm it}-\mathrm e^{\mathrm it}\right)$.

With Euler's formula, you also get that $\sin t=-\frac{\mathrm i}{2}\left(\mathrm e^{\mathrm it}-\mathrm e^{-\mathrm it}\right)$.